# Transaction Policy - How to track mass update/delete of records

Tags: apex, transaction-security-policy, mass-action

I want to create a transaction policy to notify by email a use when mass update or delete occurs. But I don't know what kind of event is generated when a mess update/delete is performed. I tried with APIEvent but it doesn't seem like it. Does anyone know on what kind of event I can find data of mass delete or update?

Comment: Not possible with Tx Security. You can write a trigger on whatever object that will "catch" a mass delete and notify you and/or monitor [Setup Audit Trail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

An interesting way to solve this is with the vendor tool OwnBackup (disclaimer: I do not work for that company)

OwnBackup has something called Smart Alerts that can, user-configured, set off alarms if in a given backup cycle, more than some threshold of updates or deletes have occurred for a given SObject.

Essentially calling attention to the admin that "unusual" activity is occurring on the database. Might be benign, might be malicious, might be inadvertent